# calim user (employee) account for the first time

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i may sound dummy , but i ran into a problem while creating claim page for the company employee.

Background:

in my company, Admin create employee account base of information given by employee,but no user name or password set up that time. (which we called unclaimed account). when employee login first time, he/she has to provide some information (To see if this user match with data which he/she provide us). if employee given information is correct let them create user name and password.

problem:

every thing work fine. But after they claim there account it take them to login page and ask them user name and password. i am trying to avoid login page. when they create there user name and password they should be able to go to there home page not login page.

any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution:

create a security token after the user sets their account.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.aspx